# Concrete over existing concrete in ground

Tags: concrete

I have a garden fence post which has some concrete on the post end in ground - had to push fence up as was tilting and now want to pour new concrete over the remaining old concrete in the ground - I have dug around it - washed it all down to make sure the old concrete is clean - will my new rapid concrete stick to this in order to keep fence erect?

Comment: Usually if a fence post won't stay straight it needs to be deeper to withstand lateral loads of e.g. a fence or gate.  Making the footing a little wider might not solve the problem.

Comment: The new will stick, a wider slug of concrete will provide more support but as Jeff said it might not solve it but it can’t hurt to try.